# A normal number could contains itself?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, normal-number

As rhe title says: a normal number can contains itself?
From definition:

> In mathematics, a normal number is a real number whose infinite
>   sequence of digits in every base b is distributed uniformly in the
>   sense that each of the b digit values has the same natural density
>   1/b, also all possible b2 pairs of digits are equally likely with
>   density b−2, all b3 triplets of digits equally likely with density
>   b−3, etc

For example if we take [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) (or $\pi$ or any other normal number) it's correct assume that at some point the number will contains itself?

Comment: No: the definition implies every *finite* string occurs.

Answer (score 3):

No.

if this point presents, P = P* 10^N + Z (N and Z are integer) => P is  the rational number.

Rational number cannot be a normal.